# Stop Location Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

whenever I try to stop my location service on android  I get a NullPointerException. anyone has some tips on how to do it? I want to implemented on some activities onstop() and ondestroy() methods. Here is my service code:

LocationService.Java

package com.storetab;

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
static LocationManager locationManager;
static Location lastknown;
final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";
static LocationListener ll;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

 final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
ll = new MyLocListener();


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

lastknown = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Log.d("Teste","lastknown");
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("location1", lastknown);
intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(intent1);   
Log.d("broadcastlast","lastknown");
return START_STICKY;

}

private class MyLocListener implements LocationListener {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



    }

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider DIsabled", "Provider Disabled");
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider Enabled", "Provider Enabled");
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("1Provider Changed", "Service Status Changed");
}

 }
@Override public void onDestroy() {
locationManager.removeUpdates(ll);
};
}
```

Comment: 07-31 10:56:36.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-31 10:56:36.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-31 10:56:36.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11337):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 10:56:36.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11337): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 10:56:36.609: E/AndroidRuntime(11337):  at com.storetab.LocationService.onDestroy(LocationService.java:95)

Comment: Your locationManager in ondestroy is null. Put a null check before the call

Comment: but why is it null? the service is only destroyed after it has been created, it makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onStartCommand()` you have this code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

This creates a **local variable** called `locationManager`, which **hides** the class variable you have declared above that at the top of the class:

```
static LocationManager locationManager;
```

The **static class variable** `locationManager` never gets set to anything, so it is `null` in `onDestroy()`.

To fix that, just change it to this in `onStartCommand()`:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```